# I can't get this simple form updater to work

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to code a simple script that will accept changes from a user via form, and then write those changes over what is currently in the file. This file is then called directly beneath the form with the current, updated data. it's essentially what im writing in currently. i want a text box that i can put text into and that text will then overwrite any text currently in that file.

Previously, these functions (e.g. request.form) worked great in other examples I've tinkered with but it seems when I put it all together for my own challenge, nothing works quite like it should.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import html

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST']) 
def home():
    with open('text.html') as contents:
        data = contents.read()

    return render_template('test_form.html',
                           the_title = 'Test Form',
                           the_contents = data)


@app.route('/update', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update():
    contents = request.form['letters']
    with open('text.html', 'w') as file:
        print(contents, file=file)

    return render_template('test_form.html',
                           the_title = 'Update complete!',
                           the_contents = contents,)


app.run()
```

and here's the test_form.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h2>{{ the_title }}</h2>

<form method='POST' action='update'>

    <table>
    <p>Use this form to edit the below text:</p>
        <tr>
            <td><input name='letters' type='TEXTAREA' value='{{ the_contents }}'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ the_contents }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<p>When you're ready, click this button:</p>
<p><input value='Do it!' type='SUBMIT'></p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

what ends up happening is the page will load fine with the data from text.html showing in both places it's supposed to. When the form is changed and submitted, data is overwritten (that is to say, deleted) but not replaced. i suspect is has to do with the way im calling the form data in the update function, but i dunno. i just picked this up a couple weeks ago and i don't get much time to tinker. i've been stumped on this problem for well over a day, though.

please help!

Comment: Try `file.write(contents)` instead of `print(contents, file=file)`. Your base route only allows a 'POST' request though. Was that by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your app seems to be that `update` route allows get requests, so if you visit that url `/update` without submitting a form, the contents will be empty and the file will be reset. You should remove `GET` method from that method list

Here's a minimal working version of your app that I've recreated. It updates `text.html` on form submit and uses sessions to flash messages to user.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, redirect, url_for, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
# https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern
app.secret_key = 'SECRET KEY CHANGE THIS'


def read_contents():
    try:
        with open('text.html') as f:
            return f.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return ''


def save_contents(contents: str):
    with open('text.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(contents)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    html = '''
    {% for m in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <p>{{ m }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/update" method="POST">
        <textarea name="letters" rows="10">{{ contents }}</textarea>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    {% if contents %}
        <h2>Contents</h2>
        <pre>{{ contents }}</pre>
    {% endif %}
    '''
    contents = read_contents()
    return render_template_string(html, contents=contents)


@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    contents = request.form['letters']
    save_contents(contents)
    flash('Update complete')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

once you run the app you get a page like this:

[image]

after submitting some content, it redirects you back to homepage, with a message and page shows up with the content:

[image]

Comment: ok, so ive had a little attitude adjustment and i've taken a step back to look at your code and it's not quite so complicated as i first thought. it perfectly solves the issue of passing the content variable from one function to another quite nicely, in fact. and i had no idea i could embed html in a comment in a variable. that's genius! i mean, i guess i SHOULD have known, but it never occurred to me.

anyways, thanks for this. i think i'm gonna ditch this book and learn python the same way i learned html: peeking under the hood.

Comment: try/except blocks are really useful for handling errors. They let you write code in `try` as if the code will encounter no issues, but when it does, `catch` handles the setback nicely and still returns a usable result. Please take your time to learn them, they are an integral part of Python ecosystem https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/.

Comment: You most certainly can embed simple pieces of HTML in the code, but when it gets long and complicated it's better to just move it into its own file, like in your code.

Comment: thanks, brother. im an old fart, but im new to programming. 

tell me, how did that text in the html variable get rendered? why was it put in the file as html and not &lt or gt? how did it even get stored in the variable if... technically, the variable has no data since everything after the equals sign was commented out? when the html variable was called in render_template, why did it not just get processed as a blank variable?

Comment: Nothing is commented out. `html` is assigned a long string delimited by `'''` triple quotes. So, it's not blank. When you pass `html` in `render_template_string` function, Flask (actually Jinja2 library that Flask uses) looks at the string for `{{ ... }}` and `{% ... %}` blocks to see if it needs to process it (like print a value or repeat a piece of HTML multiple times in a loop) using the variables we supply `contents=contents`. You don't really care about escaping HTML in your source files (converting `<>` to `&lr;` and `&gt;`), because it doesn't pose any risk as it would in a browser.